# Falldown Game with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing Falldown-like game with Unity3d. 
So my question is :
How to get the ball to fall with constant speed and add ability to jump? 
The problem is that over time the ball more and more drawn down, because of gravity. 
So if i want just constant fall i would use, for example,

```
void Update () {
    rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, -500, rigidbody.velocity.z);
}
```

For jumping i can use:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0,500,0), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

But i don't know how to implement jumping and falling at the same time:(

Help me please:)

Answer (score 2):

So, Unity gives us the option of interacting with rigidbodies either through forces or by explicitly setting their states (like velocity, rotation, acceleration). A good general rule is that an object should only be effected in one of these manners. Objects that are acted on both explicitly and via the physics engine can develop "Weird" behaviors like you've run into here!

In your proposed solution you act on your falling object both through a force (to make it jump) and an explicit set (to cause the ridgidbody to fall at a fixed speed). If you have your object physics enabled it will also be acted upon by forces! If we are interested in writing the "best" Unity scripts possible, we should probably choose just one system (forces or explicit).

You have a few options.

1) I expect this is the route you will want to go.

If you want your falling object to be managed by the Unity physics engine then your jump command is looking good (because adding a force to physics object is okay) but explicitly setting the fall velocity breaks our paradigm (because now we are interacting with the object by setting values AND applying forces).

Good news though, we can cause whatever fall behavior we want by "pushing" against our falling object with forces. To stop our object from accelerating past a certain threshold we can do something like this to neutralize the further pull of gravity:

```
if(rigidbody.velocity.y >= max_speed)
  rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f,-1*Physics.gravity,0.0f));
```

This is, of course, not a perfect solution. There will be some minor discrepancy in your object's max speeds if you just do this. But hopefully it gets you on the right track and you can tune to your liking. (Consider also "turning off" gravity for the object after it reaches a certain speed. Whatever feels most natural to you, honestly. As long as you're not setting explicit attributes (you can still look!) you're doing good.)

2) If you don't need Unity's physics engine to act on your object (which does not sound like the case) you can run your falling object's behavior explicitly by causing your jump command to simply add a flat value to the object's y velocity. But remember, once you go down this rode it's not recommended that your object ever be acted on by forces - even through the Unity physics engine.

3) Option 3 is to ignore the "rules" and utilize the solution you offered in your post. To make it "work" it looks like all you need to do is wrap your fall velocity in a check to see if the ball is falling faster than acceptable and only apply your explicit speed if that is the case:

Enable, or simulate, gravity on your object and:

```
if(ridgidbody.velocity.y < -500)
  rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, -500, rigidbody.velocity.z);
```

Then, use physics to manage jumping, normal falling, and collisions.

This is probably your "quickest" solution. But be aware that it may come back to bite you if your game becomes complex enough.

---

Hope that helps,

-Zach

Answer (score 0):

Zach has a great answer, however as an additional option...

The RidgidBody has the ability to constrain (or freeze) x, y and z.

This removes gravity and velocity so you could turn the freeze position y on & off.

Run the jump ability immediately after, or between the freeze/unfreeze command.

The pre calculated momentum will not affect the object as it is automatically set to zero.

I think this is a quicker work around but I wouldn't recommend it beyond simple prototyping.

Hope this helps :)